Injection in ASP CORE about HttpContext
In my ASP CORE project, I need to access httpContext object from a customed class called ObSessions.
Thanks to the great community of developpers, I found a solution that works like a charm, but I dont understand one line in my customed class.
The line is :  private static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
I recognise a lambda expression or arrow  function as in javascript ... but how to interpret this line ?
I know the topic is about DI (Direct Injection) but can someone tell me if this code complies with the latest standard or is the best way to access to the current context?
Can I do better than this way to access to the current user session ?
I hope my post could help others
Thanks for reading me.
Here is  the code of my class:
public class ObSession
    {       
        public string name { get; set; }
        // ..other fields
        private static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
        private class ObSession()
        {}

        public static ObSession CurrentSess
        {
            get
            {
                ObSession session = (ObSession)_httpContext.Session.GetObject("MySession");
                if (session == null)
                {
                    session = new ObSession();
                    _httpContext.Session.InitObjectStore();
                    _httpContext.Session.SetObject("MySession", session);
                }
                return session;
            }

        }
    }


Does a Microsoft expert have any idea on this ?
private static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
I tried to identify an arrow function like x=> foo but in vain.
What does this operator mean => in this case ?
How to interprete this code line ?
Any ideas would be welcome

The => just equal to = here. Actually you cannot use dependency inject in a static method/class. This way just "new" a httpcontextaccessor for you which has nothing related to DI.

@QiangFu Thank you. But if i put in my code "=" instead of "=>" I get this error when executing the code...
System.ObjectDisposedException : 'IFeatureCollection has been disposed.

I found my answer . The line is called an "Expression body definitions" and it is a "syntactical sugar" read this post  sugar

I found my answer.
I want to write it in this post ....maybe it could help someone.
The line is called an "Expression body definitions" and it is a "syntactical sugar" read this post  .
In fact , this line could be replace by this code (it works).
I shed some light on my question.
private static HttpContext _httpContext
{
    get
    {
        return new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
    }
}

